# How to access mysql inside MasterNode of the dataproc cluster?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, google-cloud-platform, hive, google-cloud-dataproc

Couldn't access mysql inside the namenode of the DataProc cluster.

```
********@cluster-***-m:/etc/hive/conf$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this might be that the mysql is used by the Hive for storing the metadata for the HDFS locations.

The user/password details for the "hive" user can be found under /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml under

```
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>hive</value>
  </property>
..
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>hive-password</value>
  </property>
```

you can use,

> mysql -u hive -p hive-password

this seems to be the default for the "hive" user with limited grants, as for the root or primary users I have no clue.